# Having a list (where items do not have ids) how to make div popups appear on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, mouseover

so I have a list like

```
<ul id="usersList">
   <li><form>
       <input class="eButton" type="button" value="robot669394444"
              onClick="openWin('robot669394444',1280,720)">
   </form></li> 
   <li><form>
       <input class="eButton" type="button" value="robot6693925"
              onClick="openWin('robot6693925',1280,720)">
   </form></li> 
</ul>
```

and empty `div` with id like `PoPa`. I want to have jQuery function that would make that div appear like a tool-tip on top of the button user mouse is over and show in that div that item value?

Comment: Have you tried anything to make it work? How is the list relevant to your question ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#usersList .eButton").hover(function(){
    //show & position tooltip here
}, function(){
    //hide tooltop here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like this:

```
$('#usersList input[type=button]').hover(
    function() { /* Position and show #PoPa */ },
    function() { /* Hide #PoPa              */ }
);
```

The text you want will be in `this.value` (or `$(this).val()` if you have `$(this)` build for other uses) when the first callback is called.